# How to connect to a SQL Database-s2 from a .php application in BlueMix

Tags: php, sql, ibm-cloud

So I have created a www site on my private server. It's basically a PHP + javascript page. Now I need to move it to BlueMix. The only problem is that while I used a MySQL db on my private server now I need to use SQL Database-s2 and all (both my php page and the db) on BlueMix.

Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to parse db information from VCAP_SERVICES\service credentials.

If your database service is "SQL Database" you can connect to SQLDB using this example code:

```
//parse VCAP_SERVICES Environment variable
$vcap_services = $_ENV["VCAP_SERVICES"];
$services_json = json_decode($vcap_services,true);
$sqldb = $services_json["sqldb"];
if (empty($sqldb)) {
    echo "No sqldb service instance is bound. Please bind a sqldb service instance";
    return;
}

//Get Credentials object (db,host,port,username,password)
$sqldb_config = $services_json["sqldb"][0]["credentials"];

$conn_string = "DRIVER={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};DATABASE=".
   $sqldb_config["db"].
   ";HOSTNAME=".
   $sqldb_config["host"].
   ";PORT=".
   $sqldb_config["port"].
   ";PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=".
   $sqldb_config["username"].
   ";PWD=".
   $sqldb_config["password"].
   ";";


$conn = db2_connect($conn_string, '', ''); //db connection
```

the information is automatically retrieved from the VCAP_SERVICES. 
The application read the env. variable and retrieves automatically the  username,host,db password field.

but you can manually set db, host, port, username, password looking at
**service credentials** of the service:

**How to retrieve credentials information:**

- from DASHBOARD UI

  1. click on your service icon in the dashboard UI
  2. in the new page, in the left menu, click on "Service Credentials"
  3. If you don't see any credentials but you see the button "ADD CREDENTIALS", click on this button, edit the name credentials as you want e click on "ADD" button.
  4. In this way you will see the service information (credentials)
- from CF command line

  *cf env your_app_name*

**In the code we are using DB2 module:** use the following buildpack https://github.com/ibmdb/db2heroku-buildpack-php when you are using SQLDB with PHP. It will install the 'ibm_db2' php module for your use.

You can set the buildpack when you push your application on Bluemix:

```
cf push <your_app_name> -b https://github.com/ibmdb/db2heroku-buildpack-php
```

Comment: I build this whole web page on my private server using MySQL, but now I have to transfer it to an IBM resource... and while BlueMix allows ClearDB it is a "third party" solution ;/ so now I have to rewrite all queries and connection to the DB so that it works with DB2 .... I can see you are an IBM'er as well. Can I please contact you if I have trouble with the code?

Comment: Crescenzo, as I wrote, I already have build the whole tool, I now need to rebuild it to host on BlueMix. I will go as far as I can and later maybe we could do a call or something, if I get stuck? 

I have a few questions:
A) the buildpack you sent me a link above to... how do I install it? on MY laptop or on BlueMix? what do I do with it? I know this is a stupid question but I am very new to BlueMix

B) in the PHP code you provided ... I am not totally sure where to put the pass word and username

C) and what is my password and user name for the DB. is it the same as my BlueMix credentials?

Answer (score 2):

You can deploy your application on Bluemix using the PHP buildpack. After creating the SQL Database instance and binding it to the PHP application on Bluemix, to connect to the SQLDB service in Bluemix you can use [db2_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.db2-connect.php) with the credentials retrieved from the VCAP_SERVICES environment variable. I don't know your business requirements, however if you want to keep consistency across the environments and don't want to migrate to another RDBMS you could try [ClearDB](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/cleardb-mysql-database/), that is a reliable, fault tolerant, geo-distributed database-as-a-service for your MySQL powered applications.

Comment: I would love to use ClearDB MySQL .... I build this whole web page on my private server using MySQL, but now I have to transfer it to an IBM resource... and while BlueMix allows ClearDB it is a "third party" solution ;/