# Converting MySQL PHP code / query to DB2

Tags: php, mysql, db2, ibm-cloud

here's a part of my code that AFTER you submit your login credentials checks your username, password, etc...:

```
mysql_select_db("robur_mike") or die ("Could not find DB!");
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Bx1_Users WHERE Username='$username'");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($numrows!=0)
{
     while ($row =mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{

$dbusername = $row['Username'];
$dbpassword = $row['Password'];
$dbfirstname = $row['FirstName'];
$dblastname = $row['LastName'];
}
```

.....

I now need to "translate" that to run under a DB2 database in BlueMix. I am already connected to the database using the code provided here:
[How to connect to a SQL Database-s2 from a .php application in BlueMix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36550945/how-to-connect-to-a-sql-database-s2-from-a-php-application-in-bluemix)

Comment: Your question is too broad, please look here http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi Jay, yeah I know it's a bit complex, I'm sorry about that but it's a complex issue. If I ask just for one component / on line or function it might not make any sense as a part of the total solution I'm hoping for. I want to be respectful of the rules of StackOverflow.... I forgot to say what the code is supposed to do ... I'll add that now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query should be OK since it is basic SQL. What you should change is the way you run it, since in your old code you are using the mysql library.

Looking at the other question, I assume that you are able to connect doing something like:

```
$conn = db2_connect($conn_string, '', '');
```

Now to execute the query you can use [db2_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.db2-exec.php) 'translating' your code to something like:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM <schemaName>.Bx1_Users WHERE Username='$username'";
if ($conn) {
   $stmt = db2_exec($conn, $sql, array('cursor' => DB2_SCROLLABLE));
   while ($row = db2_fetch_assoc($stmt)) {
       $dbusername = $row['Username'];
       $dbpassword = $row['Password'];
       $dbfirstname = $row['FirstName'];
       $dblastname = $row['LastName']; 
   }
}

db2_close($conn);
```

As you can see I've added a placeholder for the schema name in the SQL query. You can retrieve it within your SQL Database dashboard (Manage/Work with tables).

Comment: Hi Umberto,
thank you for your answer.

when I entered the code you provided I get this error message when I get to the page:
"
The davasuite.eu-gb.mybluemix.net page isn’t working

davasuite.eu-gb.mybluemix.net is currently unable to handle this request.
500
"
... the first page (index.php) works fine....